# Is this a server issue or a plesk issue?

Tags: apache, plesk, vhosts

I have a personal server still running plesk 10.4.4 on CentOS 5 (Media Temple) and I am installing a rails app on a client server (new server running Plesk 11.5 on CentOS 6.5) and when I create a new site through the "Subscriptions" panel, the output is this:

[image]

But on my server, I do the same process and the output is this:

[image]

Why is this server not generating all the config, lib, conf, etc directories like when I install a new site via plesk on my server? Is this a CentOS 6 thing or a Plesk 11.5 thing?

Has anyone noticed this or can you point me in the direction of a changelog for Plesk or CentOS so that I can be assured this isn't an issue in server setup?

Comment: Avoid editorializing in your questions.  If you have a beef about how they're being handled, post a question on one of the meta sites.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal Plesk 11.5 vhost structure.

See
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=68806.htm